# C++ async lambda "recursive" call

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda

Can't figure out why this, seemingly recursive, invocation of readKey doesn't result in a growing call stack:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void readKey()
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ 
        if (getchar() != 113) // 'q' to quit
            readKey();
    });
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    readKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you fort explaining!

:-)

Comment: How are you determining the call stack size?

Comment: No thread ever calls `readKey();` more than once. Each call to `std::async` creates a new thread with a fresh stack.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The `std::future` returned by `async` blocks in the destructor until the thread finishes.

Comment: @NethanOliver: does it also `join`s the thread? isn't it UB to not join it?

Comment: @AndyT That is what the block is.  It waits for the thread to return(`join()`).

Comment: Yes, printing the thread ID, e.g. ` std::cout <<"\non thread "<< std::this_thread::get_id();` from readKey(), shows that each execution happens on a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a recursive call because you call it on a new thread (`std::launch::async`) which has a separate stack. So when you call `readKey` in `main`, it spawns a new thread where `readKey` will be called, and exits even not waiting for it.

Comment: I say this is a very inefficient recursion using a thread and a full stack instead of just adding a call to the stack. The function calls itself which technically is the definition of recursion.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: technically speaking, it doesn't call itself, at least directly, it rather schedules that call, I'm sure you know what I meant

Comment: @RobertJacobs: The point of this code is not achieving high efficiency, but executing the same operation in an infinite loop. Kind of like event loop, only implemented as pseudo-recursive lambda.
I saw this code in some ASIO server examples and couldn't wrap my head around it... Now, it's getting more clear! :)
Thank you to all who took their time to provide explanations!